How can I seed in transmiion-daemon from the done folder after a file is done downloading in ./progress?
I have modified the settings.config with the following two attributes:
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "/home/ubuntu/dottemplates/scripts/transmission-move-and-seed.sh",

Here is my script:
#!/bin/bash

# Transmission details
TRANSMISSION_HOST="localhost"
TRANSMISSION_PORT="9091"
TRANSMISSION_USER="user"
TRANSMISSION_PASSWORD="pass"

# Torrent hash
TORRENT_HASH=$1

# Directories
PROGRESS_DIR="$HOME/seedbox/progress"
DONE_DIR="$HOME/seedbox/done"

# Move the files to the done folder
mv $PROGRESS_DIR/* "$DONE_DIR/"

# Update Transmission with the new location
transmission-remote "$TRANSMISSION_HOST:$TRANSMISSION_PORT" -n "$TRANSMISSION_USER:$TRANSMISSION_PASSWORD" -t "$TORRENT_HASH" --move "$DONE_DIR"

echo "Torrent $TORRENT_HASH has been moved to $DONE_DIR and will continue seeding."

It continues to seed from the ./progress folder instead of ./done after downloading is complete. After downloading is complete I want to move it to the ./done folder and seed from there.

It was a permission issue. The target directories need to be 777 because transmission-daemon writes as a different user.

Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, chmod 777 is wrong and dangerous. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably chmod 755) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.
